# DrawLine function changes color of my lines, when it shouldn't

Tags: android, canvas, line, draw, points

This is the onDraw method I have:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint); // Deseneaza Bitmapul mutabil

        if (shapes.size() > 0) {
        for (ShapeFromLines shapesfromline : shapes) {
            if (shapesfromline.size() > 1) {
                LogService.log("", "shapes: " + shapesfromline.size());
                float startx, starty;
                startx = shapesfromline.get(0).stopX;
                starty = shapesfromline.get(0).stopY;
                for (int i = 1; i < shapesfromline.size(); i++) {
                    LogService.log("", "----size color in ondraw: " + shapesfromline.get(i).getPaint().getColor());
                    canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, shapesfromline.get(i).getStopX(), shapesfromline.get(i).stopY, shapesfromline.get(i).getPaint());
                    LogService.log("", "shapes: drawn");
                    startx = shapesfromline.get(i).stopX;
                    starty = shapesfromline.get(i).stopY;
                }
            }
        }

    }
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.size(); i++) {
            if ((bitmaps.get(i).bitmap != null)) {
                canvas.save();
                canvas.rotate(bitmaps.get(i).rectrotateVal, bitmaps.get(i).pX + (bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getWidth() / 2), bitmaps.get(i).pY + (bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getHeight() / 2));
                mBitmapPaint.setAlpha(bitmaps.get(i).alpha);
                // canvas.drawRect(bitmaps.get(i).rect, cPaint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap, bitmaps.get(i).pX, bitmaps.get(i).pY, mBitmapPaint);
                canvas.restore();
            }
        }
        mBitmapPaint.setAlpha(255);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
    }
}
```

As you can I I have some Shapes (each shape is created from an arraylist of points named ShapesFromLines. Now the first point of my shape is from the touchDown (ontouchevent), where I save the current location. then the other points are saved on touch up. When you press the screen the first time it will draw a point, then the second time, it will connect those 2 points, then 3, etc. I save the X,Y and Paint on each point.
As you can see, I have a logservice on draw, which returns the paint value for those points. Now I have a function with a color picker that changes the color of the current path. But this manages to change the color of all my straight lines. Now I checked, when I want to add a picture, the main paint is set to transparent. And then the lines are transparent, but the points (that should be connected) have the right color. Any ideea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I created the objects, i passed the paint as a reference, and when changing it, it would change the paint also.
I did this to fix it:

```
Paint linepaint = new Paint();
        linepaint.setColor(paint.getColor());
        linepaint.setAlpha(paint.getAlpha());
        linepaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        linepaint.setDither(true);
        linepaint.setStyle(paint.getStyle());
        linepaint.setStrokeJoin(paint.getStrokeJoin());
        linepaint.setStrokeCap(paint.getStrokeCap());
        linepaint.setStrokeWidth(paint.getStrokeWidth());
pointsForLines.add(new Points(stopX, stopY, linepaint));
```

Where paint was the global paint I was using before